# Transfer Wordpress

Tags: migration

I have several WordPress installs that I need to transfer.
I had a single hosting plan under my host (SurpassHosting).
I added a reseller account.

Now. I am trying to setup accounts on my reseller system for each of these additional domains I've been hosting for friends, family and more. I've done this. But I need to transfer their Wordpress installs intact.

If I copy ALL of the files over. If I phpMyAdmin > Export > SQL their DB's. What all do I need to make sure to change to get a clean transfer without losing data?

Comment: you can use WP CLone or All-in-one-wp-migration which provide a great tools for migration

Answer (score 1):

Really everything you need to know is in the docs. See [Moving WordPress « WordPress Codex.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)

They cover exporting/importing databases, moving uploads and other content, themes, etc.

For particular issues with moving WP installs, search this site; many have already been answered.

Comment: Thank you. The Codex is something I've not really dug into yet.

Answer (score 0):

theres a nice plugin called "Duplicator" which does all the stuff for you.
http://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

Theres also one called BackupBuddy but it's not free.
http://ithemes.com/purchase/backupbuddy/

Comment: I'm going with BackupBuddy. Talked with my client and they don't want the risks associated with any other route... so yay! An excuse to buy BackupBuddy!